# Prometheus track long running processes in a HA environment

Tags: monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I am running Prometheus to monitor my system and am currently building in application-level metrics.

The issue I am having is with long running processes. I want to know how many are running at any time, and I can't seem to find a good solution for this with Prometheus.

The processes are running async from multiple redundant applications that both receive traffic at the same time. The processes run between 10 minutes and a few hours so my initial naive approach was to count a counter up whenever a process was started and increment another counter when the processes stopped.

The issue I am having here is that I see the uptick when a process starts in Grafana with the `rate` operator, but I can't monitor how many are running at any time.

Since two applications are managing the same pool of processes I can't really use a gauge to report the current number of running processes because a process might be started on instance A and then stop on instance B (or any other of the running application instances). (And the number of processes would be requested from a shared database so it would be inflated).

Now an approach I tried was to subtract `started - finished` counters to get to the currently running instance. But this would run out of sync quite quickly if the application reporting a process as finishing at some point would be restarted or die before the metric was scraped by prometheus (so I would get into a state where 0 is no longer the baseline).

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could count the number of running processes by looking at the process list on each machine (you call it instance A and B in your question). Each machine would report the number of running jobs. To show the total number of running jobs across all machines you use sum().

You could add this to your application or use [process exporter](https://github.com/ncabatoff/process-exporter) for this (I haven't use this one yet).

You might even apply a simple shell script that counts processes and populates a text file that is the served by the node collector (see textfile collector as part of the [node exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter)).

Comment: Unfortunately this would over-count by the number of instances as the processes are shared across instances.